# Use Micrometer with OpenFeign in spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, feign, micrometer, spring-micrometer

The [OpenApi documentation](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#micrometer) says that it supports micrometer. How does the integration works? I could not find anything except this little documentation.

I have a FeignClient in a spring boot application

```java
@FeignClient(name = "SomeService", url = "xxx", configuration = FeignConfiguration.class)
public interface SomeService {

    @GET
    @Path("/something")
    Something getSomething();
}
```

with the configuration

```java
public class FeignConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Capability capability() {
        return new MicrometerCapability();
    }
}
```

and the micrometer integration as a dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-micrometer</artifactId>
    <version>10.12</version>
</dependency>
```

The code makes a call but I could not find any new metrics via the `actuator` overview, expecting some general information about my HTTP requests. What part is missing?

Comment: I had almost the same problem. 
For me when I change Capability method to use provided bean registry (registry that is managed by spring) then It helped fix the problem...............................................



    public Capability capability(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) { return new MicrometerCapability(meterRegistry); }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update

I added the [support](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/commit/e745dd0c7cc84c916765337761edc7a92ad00e60) for this to `spring-cloud-openfeign`. After the next release (`2020.0.2`), if micrometer is set-up, the only thing you need to do is putting `feign-micrometer` onto your classpath.

## Old answer

I'm not sure if you do but I recommend to use `spring-cloud-openfeign` which autoconfigures Feign components for you. Unfortunately, it seems it does not autoconfigure `Capability` (that's one reason why your solution does not work) so you need to do it manually, [please see the docs how to do it](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/#creating-feign-clients-manually).

I was able to make this work combining the examples in the OpenFeign and Spring Cloud OpenFeign docs:

```java
@Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
class FooController {
    private final FooClient fooClient;

    public FooController(Decoder decoder, Encoder encoder, Contract contract, MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.fooClient = Feign.builder()
                .encoder(encoder)
                .decoder(decoder)
                .contract(contract)
                .addCapability(new MicrometerCapability(meterRegistry))
                .target(FooClient.class, "https://PROD-SVC");
    }
}
```

What I did:

- Used `spring-cloud-openfeign`
- Added `feign-micrometer` (see `feign-bom`)
- Created the client in the way you can see above
  Importing `FeignClientsConfiguration` and passing `MeterRegistry` to `MicrometerCapability` are vital

After these, and calling the client, I had new metrics:

- `feign.Client`
- `feign.Feign`
- `feign.codec.Decoder`
- `feign.codec.Decoder.response_size`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Indeed it is possible to add the capability using the builder directly. I would like to do it with the `@FeignClient`/Configuration-approach. This seems not possible yet, but I created an issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/457 and a PR is already in progress https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/pull/462

Comment: @user1451252 yepp, I opened the PR. :)